# Where is Eclipse Mars JSDT 3.6 download

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jsdt

Is there a downloadable package or how to build from the source code JSDT 3.6 with this bug fix (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425044)?

My attempt to build from the package attached to this bug fix failed with *org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Cannot find layout implementation corresponding to: 'p2' for remote repository with id: 'license-feature'*....

Without this fix JSDT throws "*Runtime disconnected*" exception.

Comment: I think the 3.6 refers to the Eclipse WTP of which JSDT is a component. WTP 3.6 was released with Eclipse Luna so there should be no need to build anything. The current release of JSDT was built in October 2014, well after this fix was committed.

Comment: OK, I'm answering my own question. I was able to find WTP 3.7.0RC2 which works and does not throws Runtime disconnected or any other exception (so far) at - http://build.eclipse.org/webtools/committers/ - Hope it helps to others.

Comment: Note - Eclipse Mars and WTP 3.7 are all in release candidate status, you should plan to upgrade to the final release due at the end of June.

Comment: @ greg-449 I could not wait till the end of June. Fortunately, I proved that Mars and WTP 3.7 can work together. The only difference is that I do not see a prompt that the debugger is suspended in the console window.